# solidity security fallback function priority

Tags: security, ethereum, solidity, exploit, go-ethereum

I know that the fallback is triggered when sending a transaction to this contract and calling a non-existent function, what I want to understand is: Contract A sends a transaction to Contract B (fallback), the solidity code has run to here The fallback of Contract B is Is it triggered at this time or the fallback is triggered after the transaction sent by A to B has completed the block confirmation!

Answer (score 0):

Former is correct. Fallback function triggers while contract `B` has sent the transaction to contract `A`.

### Why?

Because Let's say contract `A` records the number of invalid function calls for which the fallback is called.

```
// Contract A
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract FallbackContract {
    uint256 public invalidFunctionCalls;

    constructor () {
        invalidFunctionCalls = 0;
    }

    fallback() external {
        invalidFunctionCalls += 1;
    }
}
```

Now, for each invalid function call, the variable `invalidFunctionCalls` should be incremented in the current block to reflect the invalid call thereafter. Which means fallback function is called as soon as the invalid function call is triggered.